# jquery click event duplicate

Tags: jquery, click

When user click unfollow button and successfuly end the request i changed my button to be a follow button and it stills listening to unfollow function !! see code below

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("button[data-follow]").on("click",function(){

 var id = $(this).attr("data-follow");
 $.ajax({
     data: {followid : id  } ,
     url:"follow.php",
     type:"POST",
     datatype: "json",
     success: function(data){
         alert(data);
        $(this).css({"background" : "green"});



     }
 });});





 $("button[data-unfollow]").on("click",function(){
 var there = $(this);
 var id = there.attr("data-unfollow");
  $.ajax({
     data: {followid : id  } ,
     url:"unfollow.php",
     type:"POST",
     success: function(data){
         alert(data);
        there.text("follow");
        there.attr("data-follow","1234");



     }
 });



    });

      });
```

when i click follow it supposed to send request to follow url but it stills send to unfollow !!

Comment: provide your html also

Comment: <button id="follow"  data-unfollow="2542">Unfollow</button>

Comment: Hmmm, usually with delegated event binding you want a parent with the selector in the parameters. i.e. $("#your parent div").on("button[data-follow]","click", function... etc.

Comment: @JeffWatkins your params order is wrong, but the idea is good :)

Comment: this is the final and good soultion to do @JeffWatkins post it as an answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove 'data-unfollow' attribute in ajax response like this,

```
$("button[data-unfollow]").on("click",function(){
  var there = $(this);
  var id = there.attr("data-unfollow");
  $.ajax({
     data: {followid : id  } ,
     url:"unfollow.php",
     type:"POST",
     success: function(data){
       alert(data);
       there.text("follow");
       there.attr("data-follow","1234");
       there.removeAttr('data-unfollow'); // try removing the data-unfollow attribute
    }
});
```

**::::::::::::::::::::::::::::EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

Change your first line of JS code to thism its working...

```
 $(document).on("click","button[data-follow]",function(){
```

and

```
 $(document).on("click","button[data-unfollow]",function(){
```

and dont forget to use .removeAttr() also.

Comment: This won't unbind previous click handler

Answer (score 0):

use  .prop api to add a property and .removeProp api to remove a property

```
 $(function(){

        $('button').on('click',function(e){
            $(this).removeProp('data-unfollow');
            $(this).prop('data-follow','Ok');
             alert($(this).prop('data-follow'));
        });

    });
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Usually with delegated event binding you want a parent with the selector in the parameters.

e.g.

```
$("#your parent div").on("click", "button[data-follow]", function () 
{ function contents here });
```

This is because the parent needs to watch for DOM changes.